# Using node.js to send mail on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, sendgrid

**I am following [this guide (official?)](http://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-nodejs-how-to-send-email/) to send email through Azure Mobile Service with a Node.js backend.** The sending itself is no problem but when I try some of the functions for SendGrid´s template/filter engine I get errors. It´s like the functions do not exist. I am following [SendGrid´s guide](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs#addfilter) to the letter but to no avail.

From the following snippet Azure log complains and says that the `.Email()` does not exists.

```
var email = new sendgrid.Email();
email.addFilter('footer', 'enable', 1);
email.addFilter('footer', 'text/html', '<strong>boo</strong>');
```

Clarification/edit:
The problem is remotely, when I deployed the code to Azure. Is Azure using another version of the SendGrid npm-package?

Comment: have you included the line `var sendgrid = require('sendgrid')(sendgrid_username, sendgrid_password);` ?

Comment: yes, and I figured what the problem was. The SendGrid npm package is preinstalled on Azure, but only version 0.2. When I manually installed version 1.4 it worked like a charm.